# How to set options or config in SocketManager of Socket.IO-Client-Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

In android, we can set option like `transports: ‘websocket’` but I don't know how to set like android in iOS.

In iOS, I try to `forceWebSocket(true)` like this.

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://pricews8558.bitnance.com")!, config: [.log(true), .forceWebsockets(true)])
```

But I got error.

```
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: error with data: ["masked and rsv data is not currently supported. code=1002, type=protocolError"]
```

Has anyone ever seen this error before ?

Comment: I've seen this when you use "http://url" instead of "ws://url" and then set the forceWebSocket(true). So just didnt use that param to solve.

Comment: lol http instead of ws or wss